# Removing duplicates in lists within a list

Tags: list, prolog

How would I go about removing duplicate elements of a list that is itself within a list? For example `[[x,x],[x,y],[y,y,z]]` should be returned as `[[x],[x,y],[y,z]]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lists_dedupe(Ls, Ds) :-
    maplist(list_to_set, Ls, Ds).
```

e.g. your example:

```
?- lists_dedupe([[x,x],[x,y],[y,y,z]], R).
R = [[x], [x, y], [y, z]]
```

Sets are basically lists without duplicates, so this maps 'convert to set' over the input to get the output.